# No code executing after FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, bitmap, save

I write a method in Android which have to save a Bitmap file but the problem is I think this code should work but after `FileOuputStream` no lines are executed and no file is saved. Even a dir isn't created and "`Log.d("debugger", "fOut created");`" doesn't show in Logs. Similar codes I found in the Internet and comments noticed that they were correct.
This is the code

```
 private void saveFrame(Bitmap bmp, int i) {
    try {
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/Frames/";
        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, "frame" + i + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Log.d("debugger", "fOut created");
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(null, "Save file error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your exception handler get called and produce a log?

Comment: do you have sufficient rights to create a directory ?

Comment: Factually, java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Frames/sketchpad1.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
but still I don't understand why this path is wrong if I created this directory above
@Ni

Comment: @NicolasFilotto actually, I don't know but this method of creating directories works in the other cases I've done  
I don't know how I can do this another way

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail. If it fails it returns false. In such a case display a toast saying so and do not continue with the code but return.

Comment: `"/Frames/";`. That should be `"/Frames";`.

Comment: It's working. Just stupid fail. I've forgotten about permissions in AndroidManifest :/ Code is correct. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your code is not correct. I told you! If your code had been correct you would not have complained about a FileOutputStream but asked why mkdirs failed.

Comment: Also, failing to close your output stream in a finally block might end up leaking memory.

Comment: @greenapps, yes you're right but I corrected it after asking about this problem here and I haven't noticed that I put old version :/